# What is $GOPATH[i] and $GOPATH[d]?

Tags: go, go-modules, gopath

[A section](https://golang.org/ref/mod#minimal-module-compatibility) of the Go Modules Reference describes some rules for *minimal module compatibility*. There is a list of conditions in this section and two of them look like this:

- No `$GOPATH[i]/src/$modpath/$vn/$suffix` directory exists (for any root `$GOPATH[i]`),
- The file `$GOPATH[d]/src/$modpath/go.mod` exists (for some root `$GOPATH[d]`) and declares the module path as `$modpath/$vn`,

In this context, what is `$GOPATH[i]` and `$GOPATH[d]`? (Assume we know what `$GOPATH` is.)

Comment: Just like PATH, GOPATH is a list of paths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated on the documentation for the `go` command:

> The GOPATH environment variable lists places to look for Go code. On Unix, the value is a colon-separated string. On Windows, the value is a semicolon-separated string. On Plan 9, the value is a list.
>
> If the environment variable is unset, GOPATH defaults to a subdirectory named "go" in the user's home directory ($HOME/go on Unix, %USERPROFILE%\go on Windows), unless that directory holds a Go distribution. Run "go env GOPATH" to see the current GOPATH.

[(source)](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable)

Thus, the syntax you references `$GOPATH[i]` is simply used to describe an item in the GOPATH, which as we've seen can be a list and not just a reference to a single path.

Let's assume I have the following `GOPATH` on my Linux machine: `/home/me/go:/gofaster`, and I'm working on a project in `/home/me/go/src/example.com/testing`.

The minimal module compatibility rules would say that in order ie. for my dependency `example.com/utils/v2` to be resolved, Go would check:

- that I don't have a package in `/home/me/go/src/example.com/testing/vendor/example.com/utils/v2` (ie. vendor directory)
- that I don't have a package in none of `/home/me/go/src/example.com/utils/v2`, nor in `/gofaster/src/example.com/utils/v2` (ie. checking BOTH gopaths).
- that I *have* a package in one of `/home/me/go/src/example.com/utils` or `/gofaster/src/example.com/utils` (notice the lack of v2).

If I do have a package in either of those directories, then it is used to resolve the dependency.